# suggest state of text in Chinese soft keyboard android triggers edit text's text changed event

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have problem with a custom EditText and chinese soft-keyboard in editing mode:
My custom EditText with a TextWatcher:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    ... // pre composing

    // I want to clear current text and append with a new text.
    edt.setText("");   // but this line remove 'suggestion state' of soft keyboard

    ... // transform text (ex: append '\n' to end)
    ... // finish composing
}
```

*What I mean by the **'suggestion state'** is that:


- soft keyboard is in chinese langugage, when I press a key (ex: 'h'), suggestion bar on top of soft-keyboard should display. I can select a chinese word in suggestion bar to compose.*

So how can I keep current state of soft-keyboard? 
(or can I clear current text without clear 'suggestion state' of soft-keyboard?)

Answer (score 0):

After read in source code of TextView, I see the method 'append':

```
public void append(CharSequence text, int start, int end) {
    if (!(mText instanceof Editable)) {
        setText(mText, BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }

    ((Editable) mText).append(text, start, end);
}
```

the 'append' method doesn't clear 'suggestion state'.

So I change to:

```
...
Editable edtable = edt.getText();
edtable.clear();
edt.setText(edtable, BufferType.EDITABLE);
....
```

and it works properly.